# Minimum Force required for movement for a block on block system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

[image]

In the following figure, if we wanted to move the system, the minimum force we apply must overcome the static friction between the ground surface and the block of mass $m_{1}$. Thus, $F>\mu_{1}(m_{1}+m_{2})g$. In this case, the friction between the two blocks $f_{1}=\mu_{2}m_{2}g$ starts acting. I'm trying to understand if this force of friction resists the motion of the block of mass $m_{1}$ relative to the ground. The force $f_{2}$ is certainly acting backwards on $m_{1}$, but is it just resisting relative motion between the blocks or is it also preventing the block on the bottom from moving forwards. To put it concisely, I'm asking for the minimum force $F$ required horizontally to move the system. Is it $\mu_{1}(m_{1}+m_{2})g$ or $\mu_{1}(m_{1}+m_{2})g+\mu_{2}m_{2}g$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An effective way to visualize: First, suppose there is only the block of mass $m_1$ (Block of mass $m_2$ is not presented anywhere). Now apply the force on the block. It will move with some acceleration. Then place the other block on the first block and apply the same force. This time it will move with a smaller acceleration than in the first case. Therefore you can easily see, the upper block is resisting the motion of the bottom block. To prevent that motion, there should be a force acting backwards on the bottom block and that is the friction force by the upper block. The reason is: the upper block prefers to stay still because of its inertia. So when the first block starts moving, the upper block tries to go backward with respect to the first block. But the friction force accelerate it with the same acceleration which the block below is moving. So you have to provide that friction force indirectly as a part of the applying force $F$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that force *is* resisting $m_1$ from moving.

When you do these problems you draw free body diagrams. Just putting all the forces on the one object. The free body diagram for $m_1$ is $ \sum F = m_1a_1 = F_1 - \mu_1 (m_1 + m_2) g - \mu_2 m_2 g$

And for 2 is $m_2 a_2 = \mu_2 m_2 g$

And for the ground is  $\mu_1 (m_1 + m_2) g$

You can see the objects pushing on each other creates equal and opposite forces appearing in the different equations. One is between $m_1$ and the ground (+/- $\mu_1 (m_1 + m_2) g$). And the other between the two masses (+/- $\mu_2 m_2 g$). You should always have that from interacting objects, even if the forces are electromagnetic or other.